# 400 Bad Request error while downloading GAE Source Code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-400

I was getting 400 Bad Request error while trying to download the source code.

Please refer following screenshot of error for more details,

[image]

I have used `"appcfg -A [gulbrandsen-cpr] -V [version2] download_app [C:\Vishal\Live_CRP]"` command. Please guide me to rectify the given issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the square brackets [] around your parameters and put them after the command, like: appcfg.py download_app -A gulbrandsen-cpr -V version2  C:\Vishal\Live_CRP

Comment: @LundinCast It works. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: @LundinCast could you post your solution as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 2):

```
appcfg -A [gulbrandsen-cpr] -V [version2] download_app [C:\Vishal\Live_CRP]
```

The square brackets are usually used in manual pages for describing an option/attribute/parameter that is optional and is part of the manual notation that is not used when typing a command. You will see them very often.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments#download_app) however `<>` symbols are used. But if you look at [gcloud command reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/) you can see something like this:

```
gcloud app GROUP | COMMAND [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

which means that any thing in category of `GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG` is optional.

You can read more about manpage notation [here](http://www.tfug.org/helpdesk/general/man.html).

Answer (score 0):

Posting as answer for the benefit of the community: Try removing the square brackets [] around your parameters and put them after the command, like: appcfg.py download_app -A gulbrandsen-cpr -V version2 C:\Vishal\Live_CRP